# Exception handling in BenchmarkDotNet

Tags: c#, .net, benchmarking, benchmarkdotnet

I have a set of HTTP calls to benchmark:

```
public class HttpExamples
{

    [Benchmark]
    public void GetExampleCom()
    {
        var request = WebRequest.CreateHttp("http://example.com");
        var webResponse = request.GetResponse();
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void GetExampleComSsl()
    {
        var request = WebRequest.CreateHttp("https://example.com");
        var webResponse = request.GetResponse();
    }
}
```

Occasionally, one of the requests will fail for some reason.  At present, this seems to halt the bench-marking, what I'd prefer would be for it to handle the exception in some way.

Can this be achieved?

I'd like to:

- Eliminate failures from results.
- Flag that they happened

Bonus points:

- Keep measures of failures so we can see how failures affect results.
- Be able to see results for different types of exceptions.
- Do a 'thing' on failure (clean up  some what)

Comment: Umm... not to be a smart a$$, but `try/catch`? https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet/issues/170 seems to indicate it will work, with some caveats.

Comment: The iteration will still be included in the test runs.  I'd like to have iterations ignored on error.

Comment: The current version of BenchmarkDotNet (0.10.2) implies that a benchmark method shouldn't throw any exceptions. So, try-catch is the best possible workaround for now. Feel free to create an issue with your idea about advanced exception handling: https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet/issues

Comment: @AndreyAkinshin will do.  Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding manual config , similar to config mentioned in https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet/issues/579#issuecomment-345464911

Add(JitOptimizationsValidator.DontFailOnError); // ALLOW NON-OPTIMIZED DLLS
will do the trick

Comment: I don't see how that would help me.  This is a fix for an internal bug.

Comment: As you had mentioned:Eliminate failures from results. So adding this config will allow benchmark to continue running and in results file failed methods will contain N/A and time as 0, so you can Identify which benchmark failed. There is one method same as Setup called GlobalCleanup https://benchmarkdotnet.org/articles/features/setup-and-cleanup.html , personally I didn't find cleanup useful.

Answer (score 0):

BenchmarkDotNet is a micro-benchmarking harness, it was designed for a very accurate CPU-bound nano and micro benchmarks. It can do some HTTP benchmarking, but even if you use [custom config](https://benchmarkdotnet.org/articles/guides/choosing-run-strategy.html#sample-intromonitoring) you won't get as good experience as you would get with tools that were designed for HTTP benchmarking like [wrk](https://github.com/wg/wrk) or [bombardier](https://github.com/codesenberg/bombardier).